# Create 3 layers Map in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have code that calculates the NDVI for agriculture plots.
now i'm trying to create raster that will be composed from 3 colores according to the NDVI values-
red= if the value is lowe then-> Mean- (Standard Deviation/2)
light green= if the value is between -> Mean- std/2 to Mean+std/2
Dark green= if the value is higher than mean+std/2

my code knows to calculate the statistics, my problem is the **classification**.
I tried to choose each time the pixels that are greater than those ''limits'' but for some reason, when I try to choose the light green values ( between Mean-Std/2 to Mean+std/2) it choose the pixels that are in the red category.

[image: before adding the light gren category]
[image: After adding the mean]

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

//test if clipping the image collection worked
Map.centerObject(geometry,9);
Map.addLayer(clippedCol.median(), rgbVis, 'RGB');

//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');


var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};


//analyze images from image collection collection
var listOfImages = withNDVI.toList(withNDVI.size());
var listOfNumbers =[0,1,2];

for (var i in listOfNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var meanDictionary = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry:geometry.geometry()
  });

 var STDDictionary = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  geometry:geometry.geometry()

});

// print(i,'mean',meanDictionary,'standard deviation',STDDictionary);

var std2 = ee.Number(STDDictionary.get("NDVI")).divide(2);
var mean1 = ee.Number(meanDictionary.get("NDVI"));

var negBorder=mean1.subtract(std2);
var posBorder=mean1.add(std2);

var imageNDVI=image.select('NDVI');
var gtPOS=imageNDVI.gt(posBorder).selfMask().rename('PositiveBorder');
var ltNEG=imageNDVI.lt(negBorder).selfMask().rename('NegativeBorder');
var betMEAN=imageNDVI.gt(negBorder).lt(posBorder).selfMask().rename('MeanBorder');

var PositiveCOL = {
  palette: [
  '006622'
  ],
};

var NegativeCOL = {
  palette: [
  'ff0000'
  ],
};

var MeanCOL = {
  palette: [
  '00ff00'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(gtPOS,PositiveCOL,i);
Map.addLayer(ltNEG,NegativeCOL,i);
Map.addLayer(betMEAN,MeanCOL,i);

 }
```

i'm also not sure if I can ''merge'' those 3 groups of pixels into 1 raster, so if you have any idea how to modify this code it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not run your script directly in GEE. But this might help you to solve your problem if I understand your question correctly. 
Whenever you use Map.addLayer you create a layer or a map independently. What you have to do is to save the layer information into a Variable and then combine your variables into a single Layer.
E.g.

```
var im1 = gtPOS(PositiveCOL)
var im2 = ltNEG(NegativeCOL)
ver im3 = betMEAN(MeanCOL)
var combo = im1.merge(im2).merge(im3);

Map.addLayer(combo)
```

Otherwise, I think that you can also use mosaic to do this. Refer to https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_composite_mosaic to find out more.

Comment: this code doesn't work because it's not a function